# Search Engine Indexing based results and correlations to your professional life

Tags: search, pagerank

This might not be a coding-related question on its own but over the years, I've wondered about the page ranking and indexing of my search results and how sometimes I have the documentation links to the code bases as the first result as opposed to tutorial based results. It's not that important for me to just select the documentation link but I find it easier to use the tutorials on some days because of the relative page ranking more than the intent to finish a task quicker versus take more time. This question is too vague.